# Default launcher is set but not working for other user

Tags: android, launcher

I have tried with different launchers (Apex, Microsoft, envie...) the behaviour is the same. I install a launchers on a user account and set it as default launcher. When I restart my phone and switch back to that user the default launcher is used. When I check the settings the new launcher is still set as default but somehow it's not working. For the main user (owner) it works and when the launcher is set, it is triggered after rebooting but not for the other users. Ther default launcher comes always back. I am using android 8.1 with EMUI 8.2. Any help? ty